# How to set the SecurityStamp of a user in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an MVC5, which uses ASP.NET Identity for users. I have a class named Business which inherits from `ApplicationUser`, then I populate the database with the entries in my CSV files, but then in the database they don't have a SecurityStamp and I cannot seem to be able to log in. I tried something like this in my Configuration.cs file, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var userManager = new UserManager<Business>(new UserStore<Business>(context));

foreach (Business b in context.Businesses)
{
      userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(b.Id);
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Please note that initially their SecurityStamp is null in the database. Any idea, how to add the security stamps from Configuration.cs?

Comment: Try using the non-async version and checking the `IdentityResult` that gets returned.

Comment: I thought about it, but when I use the non-async version and do Update-Database, I get an error message saying: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Comment: Try changing `context.Businesses` to `context.Businesses.ToList()`

Comment: That solved the problem. Also executing the non-async version yielded correct results. If you can write it as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use the non-async versions of methods that are not intended to be awaited.

```
userManager.UpdateSecurityStamp(b.Id);
```

Change `context.Businesses` to `context.Businesses.ToList()`

The error you were getting `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.` is probably because you are iterating a set which is streaming objects from your DB and at the same time trying to issue additional commands through `UpdateSecurityStamp`